# How to display bubble on map annotation pin automatically without drop animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have a standart annotation pin, placing on my coordinates, automatically showing bubble with Title/Subtitle. When tracking my coordinates in move, the pin every time does drop animation. I tried to `annView.animatesDrop=FALSE` but in this case bubble doesn't appear automatically (for automatic appearance I used `selectAnnotation:addAnnotation animated:YES`). What needs to do to have a pin with automatic Title/Subtitle showing without drop animation?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Did you try `selectAnnotation:addAnnotation animated:NO`?

Comment: Thanks, it really works. Seems I have incorrect translated the description.

Answer (score 0):

annView.animatesDrop=NO;

It works in my code. Displays the pin without drop animation.

Comment: Yes, it works, but in this case Title/Subtitle doesn't display automatically. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the annView.animatesDrop=FALSE but at the right place. That would be in the

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

delegate method, right after you've created that annotationView.

You cannot select the annotationView in the same run loop you add it, if I remember well. I use a

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

to do it, setting the delay to 0 to have it occur on the new run loop.

In my case, I have

```
[self performSelector:@selector(selectPlace:) withObject:annotation afterDelay:0];


- (void)selectPlace:(id)<MKAnnotation>place{
//Lots of stuff for my precise case
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = place.latitudeValue;
    center.longitude = place.longitudeValue;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 4;
    span.longitudeDelta = 5;
    MKCoordinateRegion germany;
    germany.center = center;
    germany.span = span;
    [mapView setRegion:germany animated:YES];
// End of custom stuff

    [mapView selectAnnotation:(id)place animated:YES];  //This is what you're interested in
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that in this case because of a 0-delay drop animation just did not have time to operate?

Comment: No, it's that the selection cannot occur in the same run loop as the appearance. With the animation, the selection was delayed until the annotation view was in the right place (thus it was in a later run loop)